# ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting a trackable object (an object derived from `TrackableBase`), got None

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I save the checkpoint and manager of my model pretrained (in python file named train), I open an other file and I would like to restore or load the saved checkpoint and manager in order to finetune my model like below:

```
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1), optimizer=None)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, pretrain_save_path, max_to_keep=3)
```

I find this error

```
ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting a trackable object (an object derived from `TrackableBase`), got None. If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tf.train.Checkpoint()` receives `kwargs` paras which are key-object. And the object must be *a trackable object*(`None` is not a trackable object). So you only need delete `, optimizer=None`